# how to access all decode token info in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, mapping

I'm using jwtDecoder package to decode my token and store it into a userModel. I want to store all objects from this token into a model and then access the model. Guide me please

**fetch function**

```
fetchUserData() {
Map<String, dynamic> decodedToken = JwtDecoder.decode(storedtoken!);
Login.fromJson(decodedToken);
loginFromJson(decodedToken);
print(decodedToken["lastName"]);
}
```

**model**

```
List<Login> loginFromJson(String str) =>
List<Login>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Login.fromJson(x)));

String loginToJson(List<Login> data) =>
json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Login {
Login({
required this.id,
required this.firstName,
required this.lastName,
required this.email,
});

String id;
String firstName;
String lastName;
String email;

factory Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Login(
id: json["_id"],
firstName: json["firstName"],
lastName: json["lastName"],
email: json["email"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "_id": id,
    "firstName": firstName,
    "lastName": lastName,
    "email": email,
  };
  }
```

Comment: Please add an example of a token.

Comment: @user18309290 cannot share it seems but it is in json format with all these fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JWT has three parts: header, payload and signature, which are encoded separately and concatenated using periods. Payload contains a set of claims including custom ones.

> const token = base64urlEncoding(header) + '.' + base64urlEncoding(payload) + '.' + base64urlEncoding(signature)

See [JSON Web Token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) for details.

To parse payload first separate parts, then base64 url decode and finally json decode it.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final token =
      'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c';
  final encodedPayload = token.split('.')[1];
  final payloadData =
      utf8.fuse(base64).decode(base64.normalize(encodedPayload));
  print(payloadData); // {"sub":"1234567890","name":"John Doe","iat":1516239022}
  final payload = Payload.fromJson(jsonDecode(payloadData));
  print(payload.name); // John Doe
}

class Payload {
  String? sub;
  String? name;
  int? iat;

  Payload({this.sub, this.name, this.iat});

  Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sub = json['sub'];
    name = json['name'];
    iat = json['iat'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
    data['sub'] = sub;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['iat'] = iat;
    return data;
  }
}
```

[JwtDecoder.decode](https://pub.dev/documentation/jwt_decoder/latest/jwt_decoder/JwtDecoder/decode.html) returns already the decoded JSON payload.

```
  final token =
      'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c';
  final decodedPayload = JwtDecoder.decode(token);
  final payload = Payload.fromJson(decodedPayload);
```